# Prevent E-Mail to reach recipients

Tags: email, smtp

I want to know if its technical possible to prevent a e-mail delivery on the target?

Are there smtp commands/options to prevent,chancel the delivery, or hidden outlook feature.

Thinking Behind: When I write a e-mail with wrong recipient, with high confidential content to wrong person, how can I undo this.

Comment: Short answer for SMTP: no.  Also: this is not a programming question, so is off-topic for Stack-Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has a feature to undo send operation

[Link to Outlook Undo Description](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/outlook/4474-outlook-undo-send.html)